# Focus next element if validation function returns true

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have multiple inputs which allow a single digit numeric value. The script below confirms the the value is a number.

How can I move focus to the next input when a valid number has been input?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>
```

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 49 || charCode > 53)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the next element by using [`Node.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) then assign focus using [`HTMLElement.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)

To make it iterate to the next row, you have to check whether currently focused element is the last element in the current row. If so then move to the next line.

It is better to use `Event.preventDefault()` in the `Element.onkeydown` property and then check to see if the element has been filled in the `Element.onkeyup` property as the `keypress` event is fired both when the key is pressed down and again when it is released.

```js
var validChar;
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('td input[type=text]'), i;
for(i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    inputs[i].onkeydown = checkNumber;
    inputs[i].onkeyup   = checkFilled;
}
function checkNumber(event) {
    event = (event) ? event : window.event;
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (!(charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 53) 
     && !(charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 101)
     && !(charCode == 16 || charCode == 9)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
    } else if(!(charCode == 16 || charCode == 9)) {
        validChar = true;
    }
}
function checkFilled(event) {
    if(validChar && event.target.value.length === 1) {
        validChar = false;
        nextInput(event.target.parentNode);
    }
}
function nextInput(el) {
    if(el.nextElementSibling) {
        if(!el.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild) {
            nextInput(el.nextElementSibling);
            return false;
        }
        var nextSibling = el.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;
    } else {
        if(!el.parentNode.nextElementSibling) {
            return false;
        }
        var nextRow = el.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
        if(!nextRow.firstElementChild.firstElementChild) {
            nextInput(nextRow.firstElementChild);
            return false;
        }
        var nextSibling = nextRow.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
    }
    var nextType = nextSibling.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if(nextType !== "input") {
        nextInput(nextSibling);
        return false;
    }
    nextSibling.focus();
}
```

```html
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>some text</td>
         <td>some text</td>
         <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" required></td>
         <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" required></td>
         <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" required></td>
         <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" required></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>some text</td>
         <td>some text</td>
         <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" required></td>
         <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" required></td>
         <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" required></td>
         <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" required></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I suggest that you expand the definition of what's now being called an `isNumber()` function.  Pass a second parameter to it, giving the ID of the control that should be moved-to if the input *is* a number.  Then, in that subroutine, quash the event and then `setFocus` to the proper "next control."  Each `onkeypress` handler would call the same routine, but with a different next-control-id parameter, so that each control sends us on to the proper next-one.

I would counsel you:  *don't* try to simulate pressing the Tab key.